# Regular expression avoid following pattern of 4 characters

Tags: jquery, regex

Hi as I am new to regular expressions I wanted to avoid following cases of my input

```
1111 - not allowed
aaaa - not allowed
abcd - not allowed
1234 - not allowed
```

and size of string must be ***4 characters only*** 
can any one help me how can I write regular expression for above cases.

***EDIT:***

here is what I does in **jquery**

```
if(NewPasscode.match('^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234).{4}$')) {
    alert('Not Ok');
    return false;
} else {
   alert('Ok');
}
```

Comment: If those are not allowed, what is allowed? What language/regex engine are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you saying you want to allow any expression that is not 4 characters in length?

Comment: I think OP wants to detect string with 4 characters only not allowing certain pattern like all characters are same, characters are in order. Is it so?

Comment: Are you saying you want to allow any 4 character expression that is NEITHER the same character repeated four times, NOR increasing by a single character each time?

Comment: I wanted to avoid above input and string size must be 4 characters only

Comment: Compare the return of `.match()` to `null`  - `if(NewPasscode.match(/^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234).{4}$/)===null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234).{4}$
```

This will match any string consisting of 4 characters, *except* `1111`, `aaaa`, `abcd`, or `1234`.

However, it may be easier just to invert the test:

```
1111|aaaa|abcd|1234
```

This will match `1111`, `aaaa`, `abcd`, or `1234`. You can simply check the length of your input string, and reject it if it matches this pattern.

For that matter, you can just store these disallowed strings a list / array / etc. in your chosen language. Simply check the length of your string, and whether it is contained in your list of disallowed inputs. If you have many more patters which need to be rejected, this is a much cleaner method.

---

**Update**

Since it appears you're using javascript, note that you need to specify a regular expression literal:

```
if(NewPasscode.match(/^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234).{4}$/)) {
    alert('Ok');
    return false;
} else {
   alert('NOT Ok');
}
```

But if your just testing for a match, you can use the `test` method:

```
if(/^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234).{4}$/.test(NewPasscode)) {
    alert('Ok');
    return false;
} else {
   alert('NOT Ok');
}
```

To use my second suggestion:

```
if(NewPasscode.length == 4 && !/1111|aaaa|abcd|1234/.test(NewPasscode)) {
    alert('Ok');
    return false;
} else {
   alert('NOT Ok');
}
```

To use my third suggestion:

```
var disallowed = ['1111','aaaa','abcd','1234'];
if(NewPasscode.length == 4 && disallowed.indexOf(NewPasscode) == -1) {
    alert('Ok');
    return false;
} else {
   alert('NOT Ok');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but ^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234).{4}$ not work for me :(

Comment: @Ashish Why not? Please be more clear on what exactly you need.

Comment: Some engines may not support lookarounds. What is not working? Is there any error text you can tell us?

Comment: @Ashish, then you need to tell us the language as [required in the regex tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), probably your language does not support lookahead assertions.

Comment: @ p.s.s.g I thanks it works for me but one more thing how can I add size limit for input string min 4 char to max 14

Comment: @Ashish You can just change the `.{4}` to `.{4,14}`. Then the first pattern would match any set of 4 to 14 characters that do not *start* with your dissallowed inputs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disallow 4 times the same character in general you can do this:

```
^(?!(.)\1{3}|1234|abcd).{4}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36f33).

`(.)\1{3}` is matching any character `(.)` and storing it in a capturing group. `\1{3}` then checks if this char is repeated 3 more times.

For the sequences like "1234", there is no other way than listing them explicitly, since a regex doesn't know the meaning of the characters. You can check if a char is the same, but not if one is in a certain relation to another.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want only 4 distinctive possibilities:

```
function isValidPassword(password){
  var consecutive = 1,
      lastChar = -1, o = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++){
    o = password.charCodeAt(i);
    if (lastChar != -1 && (o == lastChar || o == lastChar + 1)){
      consecutive++;
    }else{
      consecutive = 1;
    }
    lastChar = o;
    if (consecutive == 4) return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

The above prevents:

- Any 4 *repeated* characters found in a string.
  e.g. aaaa, bbbb, 0000, xxxx but **not** aaab, bbba, 0111 or xxyz
- Any 4 *sequential* characters found in the string.
  e.g. abcd, ghij, 1234, 6789 but **not* abbcd, ghik, 1245, or 7890

Which would give you:

```
Password:  Valid?:
1111       False
aaaa       False
abcd       False
1234       False
foo        True
bar        True
baz        True
password   True
1112       False
aaab       False
ghij       False
1357890    True
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?!1111|aaaa|abcd|1234)[a-z0-9]{4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aMAVrts8maMWmCYY)